# Looking for fantasy fiction novel series with a male witch and dragon

Tags: story-identification, novel

They referred to the main character repeatedly as a male witch, not a warlock. I think the dragon was gold, and a pet. I think each book had a different dragon's name as the title. Each cover was a different color (?), there were maybe 5-7 books in the series, published between 1990-2005. The main antagonist in the first part was a necromancer. There was a sea port town in middle, robbed a tower towards the end?

This is not *Eldest* or *Eragon* series. Maybe a male author.

Also not the *Vlad Taltos* series, although it looks super cool, judging by the first few chapters of the story. If I recall correctly, the intro of the one I'm looking for takes place in a small town, where this necromancer is kind of the mayor... maybe a garden, some tunnels. The first scene I think is the dude and his dragon in the wild regions around said town. He wasn't an assassin, I don't think, and the thieving was for something specific, not a job. Doubtful this guy would have been in a guild or the like, very much a ranger/druid loner... hopefully edging closer; that name *Jhereg* is driving me batty though.

Comment: When you say that it had a different dragon's name as the title, do you mean *"the gold dragon", "the blue dragon"*, etc or do you mean *"Gerald the dragon", "Tim the dragon"*, etc

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/series/124488-dragonbound?

Comment: Were the stories a bit like mysteries? Main character is Liam Rhenford who learns magic after a dead wizard's familiar, [Fanuilh](https://www.goodreads.com/series/129072-fanuilh), bonds with him. The titles don't match though.

Comment: No not named the (color) dragon, I think each dragon had a name, the necro was defeated in the first book/arc and an antagonist. Vlad series looks super cool and right up my alley but for now I'll say it's not this either... Though that jhereg name sound oddly familiar I'll have to locate some of it to be sure, either way.

Comment: We suggest you merge your accounts as per http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts so that you can eventually accept the answer when you do get a correct one.

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to take a stab at it being Steven Brust's [Vlad Taltos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Brust#Vlad_Taltos) series. There are fourteen published novels, each named after a Great House (which indeed sound like dragon names), the first of which, *Jhereg*, is named after his pet dragon's species.

> Vlad Taltos is one of the human minority (known by Dragaerans as "Easterners"), which exists as a lower class in the Empire. **Vlad also practices the human art of witchcraft**; "táltos" is Hungarian for a kind of supernatural person in folklore. Though human, he is a citizen of the Empire because his social-climbing father bought a title in one of the less reputable of the 17 Dragaeran Great Houses. The only Great House that sells memberships this way is, not coincidentally, also the one that maintains a criminal organization. Vlad proves surprisingly successful in this organization. Despite being a human and a criminal, he has a number of high-ranking Dragaeran friends, and often gets caught up in important events.

- Jhereg (1983)
- Yendi (1984)
- Teckla (1987)
- Taltos (1988)
- Phoenix (1990)
- Athyra (1993)
- Orca (1996)
- Dragon (1998)
- Issola (2001)
- Dzur (2006)
- Jhegaala (2008)
- Iorich (2010)
- Hawk (2014)

[image: First book cover]

And there is indeed a character named "[The Necromancer](http://dragaera.wikia.com/wiki/The_Necromancer)".

> The Necromancer is an undead demon that was sent by the Gods in the Halls of Judgment to aid Sethra Lavode and Her Majesty, Zerika the Fourth reestablish the Dragaeran Empire as well as defend Dragaera from the Jenoine. She chose to remain with Sethra thereafter.

WillAdams noted in a comment that this specifically sounds like the plot for [*Athyra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athyra).

[image: Front cover of Athyra]

> Vlad has traveled through Dragaera for over two years. He now wears normal clothing, has discarded most of his assassin arsenal, and has lost a finger. While entering the village of Smallcliff, he meets Savn, a Teckla boy apprenticed to the local physicker. The two strike up a brief conversation, and Savn is often confused by Vlad's behavior, as he has never seen an Easterner before. Vlad's arrival in town is concurrent with the mysterious death of Reins, a former servant of the Baron of Smallcliff.
>
> Vlad shows up again at the local inn, causing a stir. He talks to Savn and becomes interested in Reins's death. While most of the village assumes that Vlad killed Reins, Vlad begins to believe that the death did have something to do with him. After some questioning, Vlad determines that the Baron of Smallcliff is still Loraan, an Athyra wizard he killed during the events of Taltos. The time Savn spends with Vlad in public alienates him from his friends in the village.
>
> Savn takes Vlad to some nearby caves at his request and begins learning about witchcraft, sorcery, and thinking for himself. Vlad tells him that Loraan is an undead necromancer who killed Reins to draw Vlad out for a Jhereg assassin. Savn also becomes acquainted with Vlad's two jhereg, who are on constant lookout for assassins. Recurring sections from the point of view of Rocza reveal that she obeys the "Provider" only out of obligation to her mate, Loiosh.

Comment: p ghost: If this is the right one, don't forget to click on the check mark by the voting buttons to accept it. :)

Comment: series looks super cool, but not it, judging by the first few chapters of the story,... if I recall the intro of the one I'm looking for takes place in a small town, where this necro is kind of the mayor... maybe a garden, some tunnels. the first scene I think is the dude and his dragon in the wild regions around said town. Character wasn't an assassin I don't think, and the thieving was for something specific not a job. doubtful this guy would have been in a guild or the like, very ranger/druid lonery... hopefully edging closer, that name jhereg is driving me batty though

Comment: That sounds very much like the plot of Athyra.

Comment: Agreed. Athyra is much later in Vlad's life where, for reasons I can't go into, he isn't a criminal anymore, though he does remember the skills. Read it anyway. Anything written by Steven Brust is worth reading. After Zelazny, Brust is my favorite writer.