# Did Steven Brust at one point claim he was receiving threats from Organized Crime familes?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, vlad-taltos, steven-brust

I was answering [a story-identification question which I think is about the *Vlad Taltos* series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149074/looking-for-fantasy-fiction-novel-series-with-a-male-witch-and-dragon) and a memory popped into my head of my brother commenting that the delays in the series had been claimed to be the result of Steven Brust getting threatening messages from organized crime syndicates on account of too accurately recounting their methods. He probably told me somewhere in the early 2000s, which was when there was a longer gap in the books. Now, poking around, I can't find any mention of it having happened, so it might have just been rumor (my brother's personality being what it is, I doubt he made it up himself), but I was curious if anyone else knew of any evidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brust did do a lot of research on the mafia for his Vlad Taltos stories, but I don't recall hearing about him receiving threatening messages. Attested in multiple places ([here's one](http://mindstalk.net/brust/psych.html)), he had a friend who was murdered by the mafia. This made him reconsider his stories up to that point and the direction he wanted to take them, which is possibly what your brother was thinking of.